# How can I check the remaining words after applying TFidfVectorizer in Python?

Tags: python, text, nlp, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

This is a pretty straightforward question, but I couldn't find any related posts. I hope I'm not generating duplicates, but here's the issue, I'm building a text classifier, which is derived from a table looking like this:

```
id    text                      cat1    cat2     target
111   'A mí, no me gusta...'    A       1        1
888   'Bueníssimo...'           A       2        0
999   'Yo pienso que...'        B       2        1
132   'Lo que no me...'         C       1        0
555   'Terrible...'             C       2        0
.
.
.
```

One can think of this as the public opinion of your product. I'm trying to put text (text column) and categorical variables (cat1 and cat2 columns) together. Target is 1 if the customer recommends the product, 0 if doesn't.

And then I've just applied these methods:

```
tfv = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stopwords.words("spanish"))

tfv_train = tfv.fit_transform(X_train.text).toarray()
tfv_test = tfv.transform(X_test.text).toarray()

# dimensionality reduction to improve sparse matrix
svd = TruncatedSVD()
trainsvd = svd.fit_transform(tfv_train)
testsvd = svd.transform(tfv_test)

# putting categorical and text-transformed variables together
features_train = np.hstack([train.drop(columns="text").values, trainsvd])
features_test = np.hstack([test.drop(columns="text").values, testsvd])
```

Since these packages are usually better for English transformations, I wanted to see which words are still in the text after the removal of the stopwords. So I was trying to plot the wordcloud, but I just found out that I don't know how to do this after applying the tfidf transformation. This is what I would normally do:

```
%matplotlib inline

from wordcloud import WordCloud

words = " ".join([text for text in df.request_text])

word_cloud = WordCloud().generate(words)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(word_cloud)
```

Any clues?

Ps.: Sorry about the oversimplification of the data, but I can't post the real one. I hope someone is able to understand and help.